# playframework application.log is created even if I use my own logger.xml

Tags: logging, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, logback

as per the playframework 2 logging documentation, I created a logger.xml and configured it to log to logs/logfile.log and roll it every day.
But every time i "run" the app from the console I still get application.log created with

```
2013-08-08 12:00:45,162 - [INFO] - from play in main 
Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

because play's built in logger.xml has this config...

I also tried putting this in application.conf:

```
logger=OFF
logger.root=OFF
logger.application=OFF
logger.play=OFF
```

but still play logs some stuff to application.log.

How do I get rid of play's logging totally? I thought logger.xml should override theirs but it looks like it does so only after "a while" and these log statements still go to application.log ...
Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help, if this is still an issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/24506476/2408961