# Play framework logger not picking format after packaging

Tags: xml, logging, playframework, log4j, logback

I have formatted the logs generated by play using `logger.xml` file in `conf` folder to get the desired format. In my local environment when i am using the normal play commands like `play ~run` or `play -Dlogger.resource=logger.xml` start. But when i do packaging with `play dist` and start the process with command `sudo ./start -Dlogger.resource=logger.xml` it is printing default logs without any format.

**logger.xml**

```
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
     <file>${application.home}/logs/application.log</file>
     <encoder>
       <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%level] %class:%method  %msg%n </pattern>
     </encoder>
   </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%level] %class:%method  %msg%n </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>

  <logger name="application" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </logger>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using Play 2.0.x - 2.1.x based on the fact that you are using the `start` script generated by `play stage` or `play dist`.
According to [this section in the docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.5/ProductionConfiguration) and assuming your `logger.xml` is in your `conf` directory, then the suggested correct config for your file would be:

```
sudo ./start -Dlogger.resource=logger.xml
```

However, it turns out that if you name your Logback config file `logger.xml` then Play seems to pick the default `logger.xml` config file from the classpath and *not yours*. Which is probably why the name of the config file in the docs is called `prod-logger.xml` and not just `logger.xml`, however that is not explicitly explained.

So rename your `logger.xml` file to something else. For example `test-logger.xml` and then the following will correctly pick your Logback config:

```
sudo ./start -Dlogger.resource=test-logger.xml
```

Comment: i am using play 2.1.4, tried this also but getting the same result.

Comment: using this path it gives file not found exception.

Comment: I tried this out on a test project and I've updated my answer to reflect what I found.